# Are bonus jewels discarded after use?

Tags: the-hobbit-enchanted-gold

In *[The Hobbit: Enchanted Gold](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/159044/hobbit-enchanted-gold)*, you use jewels to defeat enemies. Step 2 of the "Make Encounters" says that you have to return the regular jewels you used to the bag:

> When you defeat one of the adversaries, return the required jewels for the encounter to the bag and place the defeated Encounter card face up in front of you if it shows one or more bonus jewels.

What do you if you used a bonus jewel to defeat the enemy? Since it's a card, you can't put it in the bag. Do you flip it face down? Do you keep it for subsequent rounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You turn the card over after using it.**

While this isn't explicitly covered in the main rules, there's an example of play at the end of the rules that clarifies the issue. In the example, Gollum and Orcs are used for bonus gems, and then turned over.

The [German rules](http://www.heidelbaer.de/dyn/products/detail?ArtNr=HE725) can be found [here](http://www.heidelbaer.de/dyn/products/detail?ArtNr=HE725), and have the example "Beispeil" on page 7. It ends with:

> „Gollum“ und „Orks“ werden umgedreht. ("Gollum" and "Orks" are turned around.")

This is also in the unofficial [English rules translation](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/143747/hobbit-smaugs-treasure-english-rules).